# How can I kill all child processes of a certain process from the command line?

Tags: command-line, osx, kill, process-management

I run both regular *Chrome* and *Chrome Canary* (from now on, *Canary*). Sometimes I want to kill all subprocesses, *Google Chrome Helper*, of *Canary*. The problem is that they have the same name as the subprocesses of regular *Chrome* so `killall "Google Chrome Helper"` would kill both *Canary*'s and *Chromes*' subprocesses.

How can, with a "oneliner" or similar, I kill all subprocesses of Canary without killing the subprocesses of *Chrome* with the same name?

Mac OS X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `-P` option of pkill:

> -P ppid     Restrict matches to processes with a parent process ID in the
>                  comma-separated list ppid.